# Django rest Framework, change filename of ImageField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint with Django Rest Framework to upload an image.

```
class MyImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     image = serializers.ImageField(source='image')
```

I can upload images but they are saved with the filename that is sent from the client which can result to collisions. I would like instead to upload the file to my CDN with a timestamp filename.

Generating the filename is not the problem, just saving the image with it.

Any one knows how to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your image is of type [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) from django, then you don't really have to do anything, not even declare it in your serializer like you did. It's enough to add it in the *fields* attribute and django will handle collisions. This means django will add **_index** on each new file which might generate a collision, so if you upload a file named 'my_pic.jpg' 5 times, you will actually have files 'my_pic.jpg',  'my_pic_1.jpg',  'my_pic_2.jpg',  'my_pic_3.jpg',  'my_pic_4.jpg' on your server.

Now, this is done using django's implementation for FileSystemStorage (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage.get_available_name)), but if you want it to append a timestamp to your filename, all you have to do is write a storage class where you overwrite the *get_available_name(name)* method. Example:

```
class MyFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
def get_available_name(self, name):
    ''' name is the current file name '''
    now = time.time()
    stamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
    return '{0}_{1}'.format(name, str(stamp))
```

And the image field in your model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='your upload dir', storage= MyFileSystemStorage)
```

### Important update

As of August 20, 2014 this is no longer an issue, since [Django found a vulnerability related to this behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.5.9/#file-upload-denial-of-service) (thanks @mlissner for pointing it out) . Important excerpt :

> We’ve remedied the issue by changing the algorithm for generating file
>   names if a file with the uploaded name already exists.
>   Storage.get_available_name() now appends an underscore plus a random 7
>   character alphanumeric string (e.g. "_x3a1gho"), rather than iterating
>   through an underscore followed by a number (e.g. "_1", "_2", etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didm't think about doing it at the storage level! Works for me!

Comment: FYI, this isn't quite true anymore due to [a DOS attack this made possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.5.9/#file-upload-denial-of-service), but the gist is still right.

Comment: Thanks, @mlissner, I'll update my answer to include this new piece of info.

Comment: @AdelaN How would I do to save it as uploading-user-username_timestamp ? What would my FileSystemStorage would be?

Comment: @mlissner You seemed like you knew a lot about FileStorageSystem, could you tell me how I would do to save the file as "request.user.username" + "_" + "timestamp" instead of "filename" + "_" + "timestamp" ?

Comment: Just make a custom file system storage. Have you looked at the docs? They're pretty straightforward.

Comment: @VincentQuirion, in this case, you basically need access to the `request` object. Since you don't have it in a FSS class, you can either decide to use a folder with the username, or overwrite the view for uploading the image and create the name there. Let me know if you need more details and I'll try to put together some code.